# How to parse text file from PowerShell to loop through

Tags: powershell, data-analysis, azure-powershell

I have a text file with the following:

```
acl Safe_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 22

acl AzureDomains dstdomain .microsoft.com
acl AzureDomains dstdomain .azure.com
```

I want to be able to parse through this text file to get the ports and dstdomains into an array to be fed into a command in this format `"$val1,$val2,$val3"` or an array of comma delimited values of `$ports` or `$urls` as needed.

Example - `$NetRule1 = New-AzFirewallNetworkRule -Name $name -Protocol TCP -SourceAddress * -DestinationAddress * -DestinationPort "$val1,$val2,$val3"` or `"$ports"`.

Currently, it is looping through my command but my current implementation overrides the previous value which is not the goal.

Sample:

```
$lines = Get-Content $file | Where-Object { $_ -notmatch '^\s+$' } 
foreach ($line in $lines) {
    $fields = $line -split '\s+'
    $rulename = $fields[1]
    $acltype = $fields[2]
    $rules = $fields[3..4]
    #$app = $field[4]
    #$hosts = $fields[1..3]

    foreach ($rule in $rules) {

        if ($acltype -match "port") {
            $port = $rule
        }
        elseif ($acltype -match "dstdomain") {
            $url = $rule
        }
    }
}
```

I welcome a more effective way of doing this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For import with csv (given into previous comment) :

```
#importation data
$Content=import-csv "c:\temp\file.csv" -d ","

#selection columns
$Ports=$Content | where ACLType -eq 'port'
$Urls=$Content | where ACLType -eq 'dstdomain'

#format result
$Ports.Rule -join ","
$Urls.Rule -join ","
```

Answer (score 1):

If we stick with your original approach, we can use one `foreach` loop and output custom objects with the data you require. From the output, we can manipulate the text.

```
$lines = Get-Content $file | Where-Object { $_ -notmatch '^\s*$' } 
$out = foreach ($line in $lines) {
    $fields = $line -split '\s+'
    [pscustomobject]@{
        'RuleName' = $fields[1]
    'ACLType' = $fields[2]
    'Rule' = $fields[3]
    }
}

$ports = $out.where{$_.ACLType -eq "port"}.Rule
$urls = $out.where{$_.ACLType -eq "dstdomain"}.Rule
```

There is no need to create a comma-separated string since your command is expecting an array on the `-DestinationPort` parameter. You can see the additional approach below for a simpler way to just find text elements and join them as a single string.

---

**Alternative Approach:**

You can use `Select-String` to find your text. Then use the `-join` operator to create your comma-separated string.

```
$urls = (Select-String $file -Pattern "(?<=dstdomain\s+)\S+").Matches.Value -join ","
$ports = (Select-String $file -Pattern "(?<=port\s+)\d+").Matches.Value -join ","
```

**Explanation:**

`Select-String` uses the `-Pattern` parameter by default to perform a regex match. It returns a `MatchInfo` object. In our case, this will be an array of `MatchInfo` objects. Accessing the `.Matches.Value` property outputs the matched string only.

`(?<=)` is the positive lookbehind assertion for regex. In both commands, it is performed to look behind the current character for strings `dstdomain` and `port` and any white space that may follow them. `\d+` matches consecutive digits. `\S+` matches consecutive non-white space.

The resulting arrays are joined as comma-separated strings using the `-join` operator.

---

You could technically do all of this with one `Select-String`. It will likely add coding complexity to separate the combined data though. Two commands just appears simpler to me.

Comment: This is helpful, what if I wanted to get the name (either port or url) `$name = (Select-String $file -Pattern "(?<=Safe_ports\s+)[\S]+").Matches.Value[0]` cuts out "Safe"

Another question. How can I make the values = "val1","val2","val3" ?

Comment: Is the question how do you add quotes to the comma-separated list items?

Comment: I updated with a different solution to preserve more of your data.

Comment: thanks a lot man. Now I need to figure out why my Azure PowerShell command can't take the comma separated values for $ports or $urls

Comment: Destinationport takes an array. You don’t need to do any joining for that. If that is what you need, I’ll change the answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199268/discussion-between-bonafideaf-and-adminofthings).

Comment: I have a couple more questions, I imported this to csv and I am trying to achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ports=@()
$urls=@()

Get-Content "c:\temp\test.txt" | Where { $_ -like  '* port *' -or $_ -like  '* dstdomain *' } | %{

  $Split=$_ -split ' ', 4

  if ($_ -like  '* port *')
  {
     $ports+=$Split[3] 
  }
  else
  {
     $urls+=$Split[3]  
  }

}

$ports -join ","
$urls -join ","
```

Comment: How would this work if it was a comma delimited csv file(same format) ?

Comment: with import-csv function ;)

Comment: that didn't work when I replaced get-content with import-csv

Comment: put an example of your csv

Comment: "RuleName","ACLType","Rule"
"Safe_ports","port","80"
"Safe_ports","port","21"
"Safe_ports","port","443"
"Safe_ports","port","22"
"AzureDomains","dstdomain",".microsoft.com"
"AzureDomains","dstdomain",".azure.com"
"AzureDomains","dstdomain",".windows.net"
"AzureDomains","dstdomain",".vault.azure.net"
"AzureDomains","dstdomain",".windowsupdate.com"
"AzureDomains","dstdomain",".azure-automation.net"
"azservers","src","10.10.96.0/19"

Comment: hum bad format for your csv, or your exemple not put correctly your lines

Comment: between "Rule" and "Safe_ports" in "Rule" "Safe_ports" then space character is a newline character?

Comment: send me your file if you can